# packer vmware iso local and on esxi

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vmware, packer, esxi

I am curious to find out why packer is failing to get ssh access on an ESXi server. The build works just fine for vmware_fusion locally.

As JSON does not seem to display nicely directly here on SF - a link to a gist with the builder configuration: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/5acf06cb0f3afadfa347d437c2695a7c

When running

```
packer build -var-file variables.json -only=vmwarevmwareRemote template.json
```

the kickstart file is loaded, configured and installed. However, in the case of ESXi as the builder the build seems to be stuck on waiting for SSH to become available.

I noticed in the logs that:

```
/var/log/auth.log
2017-02-08T17:33:20Z sshd[94210]: User 'root' running command 'esxcli --formatter csv network vm list\n'
2017-02-08T17:33:25Z sshd[94210]: User 'root' running command 'esxcli --formatter csv network vm list\n'
```

displays a lot of the same commands.

Executing this command manually shows

```
esxcli --formatter csv network vm list
Name,Networks,NumPorts,WorldID,
ubunu-test,"VM Network,",1,87986,
someOther,"VM Network,",1,84833,
```

What could be wrong here?

## edit

packer version is latest 0.12.2, esxi 6.5

## edit2

when applying the suggestion of setting a network the same problem persists. But now I see 2 commands in the logs

```
[root@vm-bd-dev:/var/log] tail -f auth.log
2017-02-09T09:05:56Z sshd[111376]: User 'root' running command 'esxcli --formatter csv network vm list\n'
2017-02-09T09:05:56Z sshd[111376]: User 'root' running command 'esxcli --formatter csv network vm port list -w 111433\n'
```

The second (new) one has the following output:

```
ActiveFilters,DVPortID,IPAddress,MACAddress,PortID,Portgroup,TeamUplink,UplinkPortID,vSwitch,
,,0.0.0.0,00:0c:29:47:d5:3d,33554450,VM Network,vmnic2,33554437,vSwitch0,
```

Comment: What do you see if you go to the console of the vm? Any error messages? Can you reach the network etc?

Comment: The UI (console) the VM just shows the login screen (terminal). This is the same for the local vmware builder, however, the local builder is able  to move on and establish the SSH connection

Comment: Ok, the you can just login and troubleshoot your network from inside the VM.

Comment: But isn't packer (from the outside of the ESXi via ssh) the problem? Which connections / networks should be possible and accessible for packer to work? Regarding the network information: why are only other running vm's networks listed? Could this be an indicator for the problem?

Comment: Will `PACKER_LOG=1 packer build template.json` actually provide more information? according to the documentation, this should only work for local builders. Actually, https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/2185 might be similar as DHCP is used. However, we have a very long lease of 7 days configured. So this should not be the problem.

Comment: Issue #2185 is closed as fixed. `PACKER_LOG=1 packer build template.json` print a lot of debug info but I think you won't get any more info for this particular problem.

Comment: Now Packer tries to find the IP address of your VM, the output shows that is has `0.0.0.0`. It seams like it doesn't automatically brings up the VM's interface with DHCP. Again go to the VM's console and check why it didn't start.

Comment: I can see the console waiting / prompting me for login. (in the VM) so it is unclear for me why packer is not establishing an SSH connection.

Comment: And if you login, is the network up?

Comment: The proxy is not configured so outbound connections (to the internet) will not work. On a manually installed VM a ping to the ESXi host works fine) on this specific packer created host a ping to the ESXi host fails with network unreachable

Comment: The openvmware tools are not yet installed (these would be installed later on by packer when the ssh session is established) could this be a problem? Should I put these better into the kickstart file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135269/discussion-between-rickard-von-essen-and-georg-heiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the network interface to something not hard coded like

```
network --bootproto=dhcp --ipv6=auto --activate
```

solved the problem for me.

Apparently different interfaces (no `eth0`) were available on ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some more `vmx_data` settings for the network, something like:

```
"vmx_data": {
  "ethernet0.networkName": "VM Network",
  "ethernet0.present": "true",
  "ethernet0.virtualDev": "vmxnet3",
  "ethernet0.startConnected": "true",
  "ethernet0.addressType": "generated"
}
```

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Why would these only be required for ESXi and not for a local VMware workstation?

Comment: In ESXi you can define network's, the default it `VM Network`. When running locally there is only one.

Comment: But why will ESXi not default to VM Network if not specified?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Please see the edit. Unfortunately, this will not work and only change the log output.